# membership management in Django

Tags: django, django-permissions, django-2.0

I'm writing my first Django application in `Django 2.0`

My application has two types of membership level

1. Free Users
2. Paid Users

Also, there in the application I want certain `function/views` disabled for Free Users and hide elements in template based on the membership level.

**How can I manage all these in my application?**

**Is it possible to do it all using built-in permission manager?**

I tried reading the docs, but it contains few inbuilt modules and could not get how to separate it as per my requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can... The easiest way would be the `Group-User-Model`. you can use the built-in user and group management.
Simply great a group `free` and `paid` and add the user in that group.
You can query in every function like

```
def main(request):
  if request.user.groups.filter(name='paid').exists():
     return HttpResponse("You're a paid user")
  else:
     return HttpResponse("You're a free user")
```

or if conent only visible for paid users:

```
def onlyPaidUsersView(request):
  if request.user.groups.filter(name='paid').exists():
     return render(request, 'paid.html',{})
  else:
     return HttpResponse("Only available for paid users",status=403)
```

And as well in template files - you just need to define your own templatetags:

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='has_group')
def has_group(user, group_name):
    group =  Group.objects.get(name=group_name)
    return group in user.groups.all()
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way (*preferably decorator*) to restrict `CreateView` to the paid user only? or some sort of permission **can_add**

Comment: Yes there are a few options in the built-in system. Simply login to the `/admin` dashboard and edit the group. There are already some permissions on core level and on model level...

Comment: I want to check it on view level like in view check if user/group has permission to create else print message and reload same page or redirect

Answer (score 2):

Need to answer here for code formation:

sure, simply add your own template tag like mentioned here:

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

and add something like:

```
@register.filter(name='has_perm')
def user_has_perm(user, perm):
if request.user.has_perm('app_name.%s'%perm):
   return True
else:
  return False
```

and in the html-file:

```
{% load myfilter %}
{% if request.user|user_has_perm:'can_add_sth' %}
...
{% else %}
...
{% endif %}
```